# Running ground wire from CSST to house ground

Tags: wiring, grounding, csst

I recently installed CSST in my basement to supply natural gas to an outside BBQ grill. Essentially it's CSST from the manifold to a termination plate on the wall, and then black iron pipe outside under the deck to the grill.

I know I need to ground the CSST back to the house ground; however the panel is a floor above me and routing copper up there would be a pain. Having said that - we recently had the main panel swapped out and in the process a second earth ground was installed (apparently two are required here for code). I have access to that ground fairly easily under the deck. I am wondering if there would be any issue running my 6-gauge ground wire and attaching it directly to the outside ground?

Comment: FYI, two grounding rods are required _everywhere_ by the NEC.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need to use the right connector, but yes, you can do that

Bonding CSST to a grounding electrode conductor is fine as long as you don't cut said grounding electrode conductor.  To that end, you can use a clamp-on (mechanical) T-tap connector such as an Ilsco GTT-2-2 to make the connection.  From there, you can run 6AWG copper (as per IFGC 310.2.2 and the equivalent NFPA 54 text) to a suitable bonding clamp on a bronze or black iron piece electrically continuous with the CSST, *not* on the CSST itself.

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote since I'm new, but I appreciate your response. I was able to end up bonding to the brass nut on my CSST (that mates to the manifold) and went from there to the ground.

Comment: @CaryonInferno you should be able to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking you can't splice the grounding electrode conductor.

The NEC requires grounding electrode conductors to be continuous allowing only [irreversible compression](https://hubbellcdn.com/specsheet/BURNDY_YGC6C6_Specsheet.pdf) type splices *Listed* as grounding and bonding equipment which typically requires a designated tool, or by [exothermic welding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFs1yKg6JvU).

Comment: So this answer seems to be yes, as long as you connect properly to the ground rod or the continuous copper conductor.

Comment: Also you may want to verify that #6 is adequate size. The grounding  electrode conductor for most residential services is required to be #4 CU with an exception allowing #6 for rod, pipe, and plate electrodes. It's not completely clear to me that the bonding of CSST would be accepted by your local inspector.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease -- IFGC 310.2.2 explicitly calls out 6AWG as an adequate minimum for this without regard to any electrical code considerations